# How to pass some data from python3 to java

Tags: java, python-3.x, speech-recognition, minecraft

Here is my problem: I need to create a discord bot that uses speech recognition to recognize voice commands and send the recognized strings to a Java program (a Spigot Minecraft plugin in this case) from that bot/python program. I've scanned all over and I couldn't find any suitable methods to do this. The only thing that I can think of is creating a file with the necessary data inside it or its name and use that as a "bridge" between the bot and the plugin, but I don't think it's a very orthodox or suitable method.  (I tried jython, but it's stuck to python2.7 as far as I know).

Comment: Using files as a bridge between programs is not that unconventional. I think using sockets is more common, but files works just as well depending on how the communication is suppose to work. One problem you have too solve for is to not allow one process to lock the file for long periods of time.

Comment: By the way, all solutions to this problem is directly dependent on you operating system. You should at which you're using to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I assume we are talking about separate Python and Java processes since you found Jython to be not useful for your case. I think there are really two questions in this: (a) how to get data from Python to Java and (b) what format to use.

For (a) you could use a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) or [domain sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) (I believe they [now also exist on Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows/)). For the differences between these two inter-process communication abstractions [see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75904/are-fifo-pipe-unix-domain-socket-the-same-thing-in-linux-kernel). Another option would be TCP but unless there is a possible scenario where the processes reside on different machines this is not likely to be the best.

The answer to (b) depends a bit on the nature of the data. JSON could be an option but you might also want to look at alternatives that might be faster. The ones that come to my mind are [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) and [Google's Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

Comment: You don't really need a `TCP` connection between two processes, but just a local [UNIX socket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket). Of course, this answer assumes a UNIX-machine and wouldn't work on Windows.

Comment: Hi Ted, yes, that is why I mentioned named pipes, which also work on Windows. I'll check if Domain Sockets exist in Windows and edit the answer. Will also demote TCP so readers do not jump to this option.